# Call libc function from JNA

Tags: jna, libc

I use a C library from Java through JNA and one function does not flush properly (since the output appear all at once on program end). I have tried Java side `System.out.flush();` with no luck.

In brief, I would like to call C `fflush(stdout)` from Java. With JNA already there (thus would prefer if no additional library) and without C to write.

I am aware of JNA Library mapping as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296566/) but that seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 2):

The JNA library wrapping way code is actually not so heavy (at least for the flush all behavior).

```
protected interface CLibrary extends Library
{
  static CLibrary clib = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary ("c", CLibrary.class);
  int fflush (Pointer stream);
}

/* ... */
  CLibrary.clib.fflush (null);
```

JNA also offer *late binding* method and these oneliners will do what you want

```
NativeLibrary.getInstance ("c").getFunction ("fflush").invokeInt (new Object[]{0});
// even shorter
Function.getFunction ("c", "fflush").invokeInt (new Object[]{0});
```

The tedious part comes when you want to limit flushing to `stdout`. You have to deal with [vendor-specific code](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jna.user/4071) (stdout is either defined as a macro expanding to an array, [Amtel avr-libc](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/avr-libc/include/stdio.h?root=avr-libc&view=markup), to a function call, [Microsoft msvcrt](https://github.com/dblock/dotnetinstaller/blob/master/ThirdParty/Microsoft/Windows%20SDK%20v6.0/VC/INCLUDE/stdio.h#L160), or a pointer in [GNU libc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/stdio.h;h=19ab0ae0b994f446d4eaac57839d0ad2b804c678;hb=HEAD)).

For the libc, you might use (two lines for legibility)

```
Pointer stdout = NativeLibrary.getInstance ("c").getGlobalVariableAddress ("stdout").getPointer (0);
Function.getFunction ("c", "fflush").invokeInt (new Object[]{stdout});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer for Win32 / Win64 users, complementing FabienAndre's for GNU libc.

Selectively flushing the stdout stream calling the system's c library's `fflush` method via jna is hard and cumbersome. As FabienAndre already mentioned, it is difficult to get a hold of the `stdout` macro definition. For msvcrt (the Win32 / Win64 C library) it is defined via a function call to `__iob_func()`; the latter returning a pointer to an array of `FILE` structures. At index 0 is stdin, index 1 is stdout and index 2 is stderr. So for flushing stdout you even need to know the size of the `FILE` structure, of course, it is different for Win32 and Win64 ...

The following example is tested under Win64 but ought to work under Win32. It was inspired by the thread [JNA solutions to catch stdout/stderr of DLL](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jna.user/4080).

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class JnaTest {

  public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt" , CLibrary.class);

    Pointer __iob_func();
    void printf(String format, Object... args);
    int fflush (Pointer stream);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sizeOfFileStructure = Platform.is64Bit() ? 48 : 32;
    Pointer stdout = CLibrary.INSTANCE.__iob_func().share(sizeOfFileStructure);
    CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");
    CLibrary.INSTANCE.fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```